# How do you use threading on sockets for printing safely

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a project thats main thread is asking for input. I have a thread spawned that accepts clients, and then once it accepts a client it will spawn another thread for listening on that socket. However, the issue is that my command prompt does not come back after a client connects, or if they send something.

```
import socket
import _thread
from cmd2 import *

def grab_data(conn):
    while True:
        try:
           data = conn.recv(1024)
           print(data)
        except:
            print("disconnected.")
            break

def grab_client(sock):
    while True:
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        print("New connection")
        _thread.start_new_thread(grab_data, (conn,))


def start_conn(ip, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((ip, int(port)))
    sock.listen(10)
    print("Socket listening")
   _thread.start_new_thread(grab_client, (sock,))


class CLI(Cmd):
    def __init__(self):
        Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.prompt = "Prompt> "

    def do_listen(self, arg):
        start_conn('0.0.0.0', '4446')

    def emptyline(self):
        pass
    def do_quit(self, arg):
        return True

cli = CLI()
cli.cmdloop("Welcome to the server.")
```

This is the output I get..

```
Welcome to the server.
Prompt> listen
Socket listening
Prompt> New connection
_
```

What I expect to get is

```
Welcome to the server.
Prompt> listen
Socket listening
Prompt> New connection
Prompt> _
```

Another example:

```
Welcome to the server.
Prompt> listen
Socket listening
Prompt> New connection
b'hey\n'
b'how\n'
b'are\n'
b'you\n'
```

Expected:

```
Welcome to the server.
Prompt> listen
Socket listening
Prompt> New connection
Prompt> b'hey\n'
Prompt> b'how\n'
Prompt> b'are\n'
Prompt> b'you\n'
```

Comment: I assume that `do_listen()` is called in main thread, therefore `sock.listen(10)` is executed in it as well. This should happen in another thread instead.

Comment: That did not fix it.